# What's the best cache policy with Angular.js and chrome apps?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome, caching

So I have a dream. My dream is that my angular application waits as small amount of time as possible before rendering data for the user. I'm also imagining that users can use my application without a network connection.

Based on this, I'm trying to have two levels of cache. They are (these are rough names, don't take them literally) memory and disk.  Memory is stored as a global variable accessible within my application via a Service. The second is "disk" and is stored within chrome.storage.sync.

So my application currently tries to load from memory, tries to load from disk, and then sends a slow network request to get the latest, and if found, updates memory and disk.

Is this the right approach? I'm having trouble thinking about how to standardize or abstract this so I don't have to do it manually for each of my data types. It works great, but it's a lot of code.

```
// Load from Memory NOW
  if(Cache.get("receiptList")) {
    $scope.receipts = Cache.get("receiptList");
    console.log("Mem Cache hit");
  } else {
    console.log("Mem Cache miss");
  }

  // Asynchronously load from disk soon
  chrome.storage.sync.get('receiptList', function(value) {
    // The $apply is only necessary to execute the function inside Angular scope
    if(value) {
      $scope.$apply(function() {

        console.log("Disk cache hit");
        console.log(value.receiptList);
        $scope.receipts = value.receiptList;
      });
    } else {
      console.log("Disk cache miss.");
    }
  });

  // Asynchronously load from network later and save
  Receipt.query({}, function(result) {
    Cache.put("receiptList",result);
    chrome.storage.sync.set({'receiptList':result});
    $scope.receipts = result;
    console.log("Caches set from network.");
  });
```

Comment: I am facing the exact same issue! I also found that the default angular cache (or any advanced alternatives like angularCacheFactory) are not good enough: they don't use cache control headers. The end goal for me is even harder: I would like to load the data from cache ALWAYS, and then access the network resource: if I get a 304 (not modified), I am done. Else, I update the (already rendered) data again. This I believe gives the fastest response time for my needs. The best solution I can think of is extending the ng-resource service - is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

The best techniques i know to improve load time and/or rendering time of Angular apps are:

- Preloading HTML templates
- Preloading non-HTML resources

https://medium.com/p/f8ae57e2cec3

- Work on optimizations of the critical rendering path
  https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1IRHyU7_crIiCjl0Gvue0WY3eY_eYvFQvSfwQouW9368/present#slide=id.p19